# PHPExcel getConditionalStyles() method returns empty array

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpexcel-1.8.0

I've applied a conditional formatting rule for column B in the excel sheet. When I'm trying to get the conditional styles of that particular cell, I get an empty array. I am using the below code to get the conditional styles.

```
$conditionalStyles = $PHPExcelObj->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B4')->getConditionalStyles();
```

I've used setReadDataOnly(false), so as to get all style info.
Below is the code I am using to create the reader object.

```
$PHPExcelObj   = new PHPExcel;
$InputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($path);
$ObjReader     = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($InputFileType);
$ObjReader->setReadDataOnly(false);
$PHPExcelObj->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$conditionalStyles = $PHPExcelObj->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B4')->getConditionalStyles();
```

I couldn't find out what I am doing wrong. Any leads would be very helpful. Thanks

**Edit1:**

The original file was a .xls file. After I saved it as .xlsx file, I am able to get the conditional styles. The getConditionalStyles() method only works with .xlsx files?

**Edit2:**

Even with a .xlsx file, it only partially shows the conditional styles. For some cells, even if there is a conditional style rule, it does not show those.
Can any one give any idea how can I achieve this. My goal is to get the style info of the cells such as background-color, font-weight, and all.Are there any other Excel reading libraries that I can use apart from PHPExcel?

Answer (score -1):

Try it without getStyle:

```
$conditionalStyles = $PHPExcelObj->getActiveSheet()->getConditionalStyles('B4');
```